# How do I get the most recent date before todays date with conditions in an SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on quite a complex SQL query.  The query is for car hire and reports back all the vehicles we currently have and shows their current "live" hire agreement (if it exists) and it also shows the cars NEXT hire agreement if that exists.

The problem I have is that, in my approach to make this work, the next hire agreement vanishes once the current hire agreement reaches its end date.  That is because I'm using an OUTER APPLY and that forces the next hire agreement to rely on the current hire agreement data.

The live status of the agreements is controlled by the user and is a boolean value populated via a checkbox.

I need to prevent the next hire agreement date from vanishing from my results when the current live agreement date passes and I'm not sure how to accomplish this.  Can anyone help?

Please see my current query and observe the outer apply which, I don't think is really working for what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
SELECT
/*********************** 
    #Car Agreements
***********************/ 
uve.[Id], 
uve.[ViewId], 
uve.[VehicleId], 
ve.[Name],

/***********************  
    #Hire Agreement (Current)
***********************/ 
CAST((CASE WHEN fix1.[Id] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE fix1.[Id] END) AS INT) AS [FixtureId], 
fix1.[Date], 
fix1.[FirmUntil], 
fix1.[Broker], 
fix1.[WorkRole], 
fix1.[Charterer],

/***********************  
    #Hire Agreement (Next)
***********************/ 
fix2.Id AS NextFixtureId, 
fix2.[Date] AS NextOnhire, 
fix2.[FirmUntil] AS NextOffhire, 
fix2.[Charterer] AS NextCharterer,       

FROM UserVehicles AS uve 

LEFT JOIN Vehicle AS ve ON ve.Id = uve.VehicleId 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Id], [Date], [FirmUntil], [Live], [VehicleId]
        FROM Fixture
        WHERE Live = '1') AS fix1 ON fix1.[VehicleId] = ve.Id 
        OUTER APPLY
      (SELECT TOP 1 [Id], [Date],[Live],[FirmUntil]
        FROM Fixture AS f2
        WHERE uve.[VesselId] = f2.[VehicleId] AND ((CAST(f2.Date AS date)) >= (CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) OR f2.Date > fix1.FirmUntil)) AS fix2   
ORDER BY [Date] Desc
```

I personally think that the outer apply isn't quite what I need for this setup and I should perhaps make a separate join assessing the dates and picking the most recent date before the current date-time that is not live but I will take some guidance on that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post sample data and expected results.  DDL to create it would be ideal.

Comment: Use `LEAD/LAG` window functions. You will need to put `Fixture` into a derived table